# EnumMap & streams

Tags: java, collections, enums, java-8, java-stream

Hi tried to figure out how to map to a EnumMap without success. 
At the moment I'm doing it in 2 steps, I create the map and then I make it a EnumMap. 
Question are.

1. Is it possible to do it in only one step?
2. From efficiency perspective would be better to get Values from
   input, make them a set and then stream it, or just using  toMap as
   its right now is correct. thanks

   ```
   Map<CarModel, CarBrand> input...  
   final Map<CarBrand, CarsSellers> ret = input.values()
               .stream().filter(brand -> !brand.equals(CarBrand.BMW))
               .collect(toMap(Function.identity(), brand -> new CarsSellers(immutableCars, this.carsDb.export(brand))));

    final EnumMap<CarBrand, CarsSellers> enumMap = new EnumMap<>(CarBrand.class);
       enumMap.putAll(ret);
   ```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## TL;DR: You need to use the [other `toMap` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-).

By default a `toMap` uses `HashMap::new` as the `Supplier<Map>` - you need to supply a new `EnumMap` instead.

```
final Map<CarBrand, CarsSellers> ret = input.values()
        .stream()
        .filter(brand -> brand != CarBrand.BMW)
        .collect(toMap(
                identity(),
                brand -> new CarsSellers(immutableCars, this.carsDb.export(brand)),
                (l, r) -> {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Duplicate keys " + l + "and " + r + ".");
                },
                () -> new EnumMap<>(CarBrand.class)));
```

Arguments are:

1. the `key` extractor
2. the `value` extractor
3. a "mergeFunction" that takes two values, one that already exists in the `Map` and one to be added. In this case, we simply throw an `IllegalArgumentException` as keys should be unique
4. the "map supplier" - this returns a new `EnumMap`.

---

Notes on your code:

1. program to the `interface` - `Map` not `EnumMap`
2. `enum` is singleton, so you can use `a != Enum.VALUE`
3. an `import static` for `Function.identity()` makes things less verbose

Comment: Thanks for the help, I read that forloops are more efficient than stream. Does it apply when we are talking about toMap, if I do the same using for  instead. Will it be faster?

Comment: @Hook with Java it's very hard to say whether a micro-optimisation will be faster. It is very likely that a plain loop _will_ be faster as there are many fewer moving parts. I would recommend you familiarise yourself with [jmh](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) and get a definitive answer for your exact code.